# R Set Column Value based on other Column Values

Tags: r

I need to set the values of a column to 0 or 1 based on other columns values.

If they are 0 or NA the new column should be 1.

I Thought about:

```
ifelse(df[,53:62]==0|NA, df$newCol <- 1, df$newCol <- 0)
```

But I the End I get only 1 in the new Column

Thanks for your help

Comment: I answered your question but your code has a few r problems, you can't do ==0|NA it needs to be in the long form, you should not do == NA, instead use is.na(), you shouldn't assign inside ifelse function, functions should remain pure

Comment: this is what I figured out now 
`df$newCol <- ifelse(df[,53:62]==0|is.na(df[,53:62]),1,0)`

Comment: Are you sure the above gives you the expected output that you want?

Comment: @RonakShah another one bites the dust.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tidyverse fits perfectly on this common use case

```
library(tidyverse)

df_example <- matrix(c(0,1),ncol = 100,nrow = 100) %>% 
  as_tibble()


df_example %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = 53:62,
                .fns = ~ if_else(.x == 0|is.na(.x),
                                 1,
                                 0))
  ) %>% 
  select(V54) # example**
```