# R set binary flag based on contents of other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have tried the dplyr solution in [R Set Column Value based on other Column Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65738187/r-set-column-value-based-on-other-column-values#comment116336647_65738187), but when I run it I get the columns all repeated as THING$THING1 etc when I need just one column that flags as 1, when any of the columns THING1:THING4 contain a 1, and 0 if none of them do. (The data is using 1 for yes as the answer to a series of related questions, and 0 for no.)

| Thing1 | Thing2 | Thing3 | Thing4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

And I want the to get the column:

| Thing |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 0 |

The code as I'm using it is:

```
Things <- dataset %>%
  select(c(THING1:THING4)) %>%
  mutate(THING = across(.cols = THING1:THING4,
                .fns = ~ if_else(.x == 1|is.na(.x),
                                 1,
                                 0)))
```

I am using a vector as the real data has about a dozen columns to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one potential solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = "Thing1 Thing2  Thing3  Thing4
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   1   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0", header = TRUE)

df %>%
  mutate(flag = as.numeric(if_any(starts_with("Thing"), ~.x == 1)))
#>   Thing1 Thing2 Thing3 Thing4 flag
#> 1      0      0      0      0    0
#> 2      1      0      0      0    1
#> 3      0      1      0      1    1
#> 4      0      0      0      0    0
#> 5      0      0      1      0    1
#> 6      1      0      0      0    1
#> 7      0      0      0      0    0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit

In the code in your question I see you can have NAs too. If you want to 'ignore' NA's you could use:

```
df %>%
  mutate(flag = as.numeric(if_any(starts_with("Thing"), ~.x == 1 & !is.na(.x))))
#>   Thing1 Thing2 Thing3 Thing4 flag
#> 1      0      0      0      0    0
#> 2      1      0      0      0    1
#> 3      0      1      0      1    1
#> 4      0      0      0     NA    0
#> 5      0      0      1     NA    1
#> 6      1      0      0      0    1
#> 7      0      0      0      0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is making the same operation on several columns, instead of summarizing several columns. If you want to use `across` (rather than `if_any`) you could make use of `rowSums`.

```r
df |>
  mutate(Thing = as.numeric(rowSums(across(Thing1:Thing4), na.rm = TRUE) >= 1))
```

If you want to adapt your own implementation, you could use `rowwise()` (and `any()`):

```r
df |>
  #select(c(Thing1:Thing4)) |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(Thing = if_else(any(c_across(Thing1:Thing4) == 1) | any(is.na(c_across(Thing1:Thing4))), 1, 0)) |>
  ungroup()
```

Data from @jared_mamrot